# Две простые задачи в Python на цикл

Tags: python, циклы

Я новичок, учусь в колледже, не знаю, как сделать следующие задачи на цикл:

1. Вводятся два натуральных числа. Определить цифры, входящие в запись как первого, так и второго числа.
2. Вводятся целые числа до первого числа, которые меньше двух. Написать программу, которая определяет, сколь простых чисел было введено.

Можете помочь написать коды без сложных формул? через int

Comment: А что сделали вы? Помочь и сделать за вас - разное

Comment: 2 других задач ) эти я не могу сообразить

Answer (score 1):

1 задача решается с использованием `%` - определение остатка от деления

в данном случае нужно определять остаток от деления числа на 10 и уменьшать число в 10 раз, т.е. решать вот такую задачу `b = 10a + x` - определять `x` и переходить к от `b` к `a`

2 задача делается через определение делителей числа `n` от `2` до `sqrt(n)` - если делителей нет (опять через `%` определяется), то число - простое